# Can a Kafka consumer read records from a Broker's page cache?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka's documentation clearly states that messages/records are immediately written to the file system as they are received by the Broker. With the default configuration, this means that the Broker flushes records to the page cache immediately and later the Kernel can flush it to disk.

My question is: can a consumer read a record that is in the page cache but that has not yet been flushed to disk by the kernel?

If the answer is yes, how will the consumer keep track of the offset it reads from?

If the answer is no, then it would mean that the record has to be read back from disk to the page cache before it is sent out to NIC via zero-copy. Correct?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there is a read/write operation to the file, the data is written/fetched to page cache first. In case of read, if the data is already present in cache page the actual disk read is not called and data is served from page cache. It's not that kafka consumer is reading from page cache of broker but this is being done by file system and hidden from actual read call. In most of the cases, the records from kafka are read sequentially which allows it to use page cache effectively.

zero-copy optimization is used in every read from kafka client, copying data directly from page cache to NIC buffer.